# ¿Por qué mi imagen .svg no se ve?

Tags: html, css, web, svg

estoy intentando aplicar una imagen .svg a mi sitio, pero cuando lo hago no se ve, aunque si está ahí. Es como si se pusiera transparente, como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: '''''']

Comment: intenta cambiando el img por embed <embed>

Comment: puedes poner un enlace hacia trebol.svg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debes tener problema en cargar el .SVG,

```
<img src="multimedia/logos/trebol.svg" type="img/svg">
```

el problema puede ser debido a estas causas:

- El archivo .svg es incorrecto, si deseas revisar en verdad sea un .svg puedes usar algún visor para revisar que funciona correctamente:
  https://www.freecodeformat.com/svg-editor.php
- El archivo no existe o la ruta es incorrecta, de acuerdo a tu código la imagen debe encontrarse en

  https://<dominio de página>/multimedia/logos/trebol.svg

en este caso el problema puede ser causado porque posiblemente le hace falta un "/" a la ruta relativa definida para la imagen:

```
<img src="/multimedia/logos/trebol.svg" type="img/svg">
```